# How to add a non-numeric character to a certain element in numpy matrix?

Tags: python, list, numpy, matrix, character

Say I have a numpy matrix as such as such:

```
matrix = np.zeros((5,5))

# goes through code that changes value of matrix to get:

[[0. 4. 7. 1. 3.]
 [5. 6. 8. 0. 1.]
 [inf inf 5. 2. 5.]
 [4. 6. 2. 1. inf]]
```

When printing this matrix, I want to add 2 asterisk symbols on either side of certain elements:

```
[[0. *4* 7. 1. 3.]
 [5. 6. *8* 0. 1.]
 [inf inf 5. 2. 5.]
 [4. *6* 2. *1* inf]]
```

How would I go about doing this?

I tried:

```
 matrix_output = matrix
 matrix_output[i][j] = '*' + str(matrix_for_print[i][j]) + '*'
```

But I get this error:

```
 builtins.ValueError: could not convert string to float: '*4.0*'
```

(Also, side note, how do I get the matrix to just have commas instead of decimals like here. So ideally, I would like:

```
[[0, *4*, 7, 1, 3]
 [5, 6, *8*, 0, 1]
 [inf, inf, 5, 2, 5]
 [4, *6*, 2, *1*, inf]]
```

Comment: It sounds like you're mixing up data and presentation. If you want to have asterisks in the output when you present output to the user, you should do that in your output formatting code, not by trying to stick a bunch of asterisks in your array itself. The array represents numerical data.

Comment: @user2357112 Yes, that is what I'm trying to do, meaning printing the matrix with '*'. I'm just not sure how to print it as such.

Comment: `matrix` is now a `ndarray` with `float` dtype. `inf` is a float.   `alist = matrix.tolist()`, makes a nested list of lists.  You could then change elements from number to string `"*8*"`.  List display also includes commas (numpy array normally omits those).

Answer (score 0):

I wonder if those tweaks are really worth it?.  But first make sure you understand what objects you have at each stage, and why they display as they do.

Start with a simpler array like yours:

```
In [163]: arr = np.array([[0, 4,7],[np.inf, 0,3]])                                                           
In [164]: arr                                                                                                
Out[164]: 
array([[ 0.,  4.,  7.],
       [inf,  0.,  3.]])
In [165]: arr.dtype                                                                                          
Out[165]: dtype('float64')
```

Even though the numbers are integers, the dtype is float.  `np.inf` is float.  Also `np.zeros` makes a float by default.

You could change it to a list of lists:

```
In [166]: alist = arr.tolist()                                                                               
In [167]: alist                                                                                              
Out[167]: [[0.0, 4.0, 7.0], [inf, 0.0, 3.0]]
```

note that this display includes the commas, and 0's.  And doesn't divide it into rows.  But being a list we can change individual items to strings:

```
In [168]: alist[0][2] = '*7*'                                                                                
In [169]: alist                                                                                              
Out[169]: [[0.0, 4.0, '*7*'], [inf, 0.0, 3.0]]
```

and even back to a character array:

```
In [170]: np.array(alist)                                                                                    
Out[170]: 
array([['0.0', '4.0', '*7*'],
       ['inf', '0.0', '3.0']], dtype='<U32')
```

`print` of that would omit the commas and dtype, but still show the quotes.

We can also convert it to character array with:

```
In [171]: arr.astype(str)                                                                                    
Out[171]: 
array([['0.0', '4.0', '7.0'],
       ['inf', '0.0', '3.0']], dtype='<U32')
```

And change a string.  Pay attention to the dtype size.  Here is it 32 char wide.  If it had been `'<U3'` we couldn't have added the extra characters.

```
In [172]: _[0,2] = '*7*'                                                                                     
In [173]: _171                                                                                               
Out[173]: 
array([['0.0', '4.0', '*7*'],
       ['inf', '0.0', '3.0']], dtype='<U32')
```

To get rid of the decimals we could convert to `int` dtype - but that messes up the `inf`.

```
In [174]: arr.astype(int)                                                                                    
Out[174]: 
array([[                   0,                    4,                    7],
       [-9223372036854775808,                    0,                    3]])
```

So there limits as to what you can do to an array, and still display all elements in a consistent manner.

But if you are picky enough, you could format the array (or lists of lists) explicitly, using standard Python formatting expressions.  For example:

```
In [185]: astr = []                                                                                          
In [186]: for row in arr: 
     ...:     str1 = ['%s'%i for i in row] 
     ...:     astr.append(str1) 
     ...:                                                                                                    
In [187]: '\n'.join([', '.join(row) for row in astr])                                                        
Out[187]: '0.0, 4.0, 7.0\ninf, 0.0, 3.0'
In [188]: print(_)                                                                                           
0.0, 4.0, 7.0
inf, 0.0, 3.0
```

With the `joins` I produce just one string, rather than an array or list of strings.  That gets rid of the quotes.  I'd have add further tests to change the floats to int, without harming the `inf`.  And somehow also identify which elements get the *.  You could write a function that takes an element, and takes care of all the integer versus float (or inf) details as well as adding the highlighting.

The `__str__` or `__repr__` methods of a custom class require the same sort of attention to formatting detail. When your expectations deviate enough from common practice, there's no way around this.